# GCC equivalent of llvm-link

Tags: gcc, hyperlink, llvm

I use the following LLVM tools to convert a cpp project which is written in multiple files into "ONE" single assembly file.

```
clang      *.cpp   -S -emit-llvm
llvm-link  *.s     -S -o all.s
llc        all.s   -march=mips
```

Is there any way of doing this in GCC? In particular, is there any way of linking GCC generated assembly files into one assembly file? i.e., what is the equivalent of LLVM-LINK?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [LTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-time_optimization) (Link Time Optimization) is what you want.

Then, compile each compilation unit with `gcc -flto` e.g.

```
gcc -flto -O -Wall -c src1.c
g++ -flto -O -Wall -c src2.cc
```

and use also `-flto` (and the same optimizations) to link them:

```
g++ -flto -O src1.o src2.o -lsomething
```

LTO works in GCC by putting, in each generated assembly file and object file, some representation of the internal GCC representations (like Gimple). See [its documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html#LTO)

You might want to use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to customize GCC (or simply use its probe to understand the Gimple, or try just `gcc -fdump-tree-all`).